# XSLT is adding additional characters to HTML image elements

Tags: html, xml, image, xslt

So I am creating a webpage from an XML file that I created.  It is a list of all cards and their attributes from Hearthstone.

When it comes to images can someone explain why my xsl transformation is adding character data to the begging and end of my img content output?  It does this even when I use a local image.  I am using jEdit.

XML:

```
<Image_URL>
        <regular>
        http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/3/37/Abomination%28597%29.png/184px-Abomination%28597%29.png?version=9e47af5b792479ac6617cb30bf7da8a4
        </regular>

        <gold>
        http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/1/10/Abomination%28597%29_Gold.png/184px-Abomination%28597%29_Gold.png?version=a340c375a36e6c10eec4a747a3170901
        </gold>
    </Image_URL>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="regular">
    <p>
        <img src="{.}"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<img src="%0A%09%09%09http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/hearthstone.gamepedia.com/thumb/3/37/Abomination%28597%29.png/184px-Abomination%28597%29.png?version=9e47af5b792479ac6617cb30bf7da8a4%0A%09%09%09"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing the additional whitespace surrounding the URL data, given that the element is pretty-printed.

Use `normalize-space` in the attribute value template to remove this:

```
<xsl:template match="regular">
    <p>
        <img src="{normalize-space(.)}"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Lol! duh!  Thanks!  I don't know what I was thanking.